# What does \bibitem and \BibitemOpen do in reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing

Normally I do reference by

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\printbibliography
```

where in the `reference.bib` there are

```
@book{,
    author        = {},
    title         = {},
    year          = {},
    volume = {},
    publisher     = {},
    ISBN = {}
}
```

But in the articles in aps, many people do reference in a way that I never see before.

There are commands like `\bibitem` `\BibitemOpen` ..... that I have not seen before.

For example:

```
 \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {}~\bibnamefont
  {}},\ }\href {} {\bibfield
  {journal} {\bibinfo  {journal} {}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo
  {volume} {}},\ \bibinfo {pages} {} (\bibinfo {year}
  {})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {}()}]{}%
```

In what way should I use these reference commands? Where can I create such format? Is this another way to do reference?

Answer (score 2):

You've got two things going on here.

The command `\bibitem` is one from the LaTeX kernel. If one chooses to write the bibliography by hand

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem Some entry
\bibitem A second entry
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

then `\bibitem` is used in place of the 'normal' `\item` in the dedicated list structure. If one is using a BibTeX database (the common approach) then this is the structure you will find in the `.bbl` file created by BibTeX, but you never type in in by hand.

Within a `.bbl` file created by `natbib`, you will find additional macros inserted to allow the package to pick up and manipulate the bibliography from within the LaTeX run. It is `natbib` that defines `\BibitemOpen` and related commands. The source for the package has comment:

```
% \changes{8.2}{2008 Jul 13}{(AO) Allow optional arguments preceding cite key.}
% We give meanings to \cs{bibitemOpen} and \cs{bibitemShut};
% the default is \verb+\relax+. Special .bst files take care of inserting markup into
% the .bbl file. There, each \cs{bibitem} begins with \cs{BibitemOpen} andbibitemOpen
% ends with \cs{BibitemShut}.
```

Following through, as stated in the above `\bibitemOpen` and `\bibitemClose` are equal to `\relax` so do nothing. The standard definition of `\BibitemOpen` is just a wrapper around `\bibitemOpen` (so a no-op), whilst we have something a bit more involved for `\BibitemShut`:

```
\def\BibitemShut#1{%
 \def\@bibstop{#1}%
 \let\bibitem@Stop\bibitemStop
 \let\bibitem@NoStop\bibitemNoStop
 \@ifx{\bibitemShut\relax}{\let\@bibitemShut\@empty}{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@bibitemShut\expandafter{\bibitemShut}%
 }%
}%
\def\@bibitemShut{}%
\def\bibitemStop{\@bibitemShut}%
\def\bibitemNoStop{%
 \@ifx{\@empty\@bibitemShut}{.\spacefactor\@mmm\space}{\@bibitemShut}%
}%
\def\bibitemContinue{%
 \@ifx{\@empty\@bibitemShut}{;\spacefactor\@mmm\space}{\@bibitemShut}%
}%
```

The above is used to tell if an entry ends with a full stop (period): this is useful if entries are being compressed into the form "1. a) ... b) ... c ..."

The only `.bst` files that write such data in a standard TeX installation are those in the REVTeX bundle, so as you say related to the APS and so on.

---

Note that if one is using `biblatex` the BibTeX database (`.bib` file) is the same but the way the `.bbl` file works is entirely different. As such, it does not contain `\bibitem` lines.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51522/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-what-does-bibitem-and-bibitemopen-do-in).